# Null Pointer Exception from class array

Tags: java, arrays, class

I want to make an array of size 150 of the class Info

```
public class Info {
    int Group;
    String Name;
}
```

But I have the exception occur after

```
 public class Mover {
        static Info[] info=new Info[150];
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            info[0].Group=2;//I get error here
        }
}
```

I'm not sure if there is a better way to do what a want to do, but I don't want to use a multidimensional array. I'm simply trying to add information to the group, so I'm confused.

Comment: First you've to create `Info` object, then only you can set value to its attribute.

Comment: You have to initialize an object before you can use the methods

Comment: Assign objects in your array ... currently info[0] ... info[n] are null and any operation on these array elements will lead to NPE

Comment: This really should be marked as a duplicate of something, but I can't find any of the other 15,326 questions that have asked this.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I just thought that it would automatically instantiate each of the locations

Answer (score 1):

doing `new Info[150]` simply instantiates an array of size 150. All elements within the array have not been instantiated and are therefore null.

So when you do `info[0]` it returns null and you're accessing `null.Group`.

You have to do `info[0] = new Info()` first.

Comment: Do you know how I can do that in a simple command rather than typing it all out? Btw, thanks alot.

Comment: Yeah, you can do `Arrays.fill(info, new Info())` and it will instantiate all elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

This `static Info[] info=new Info[150];` is creating an array of 150 objects of type info pointing to NULL.
You have to do this to get this working

`for(int i = 0; i< 150; i++)
  info[i] = new Info();`

Then you can use these objects